# I need to extract the lower and higher number of sequence

Tags: c++, variables, sequence

I'm using a sequence of x numbers and search the lower and higher number of it and calculate the diff, but when I use a variable to save the highest number it don't save, I don't have that problem with the lower variable.

```
for(int i=0;i<mesos;i++){
cin >>m;
if(m<e) a = m;
else if(m<e) e = m;
```

all is declared

Comment: You use the exact same check in both ifs. Furthermore the first value may be the largest or the smallest value of the sequence. In your code snippet I assume you only ever assign the first value to `a`, but cannot be sure, since the initialization and is missing from the code snippet.

Comment: Btw: I strongly recommend using identifiers that actually tell you, what the variable stands for; how long will it take you to figure out, what `a` and what `e` stands for, if you read through the code in a month? Changing the names to `minValue` and `maxValue` would prevent this issue and in most IDEs you can do this in seconds via rename functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To save the highest number you have to test if the number is greater than another number. In your case you're calculating against the same value, the same thing. I didn't test my resolution but it would be something like what I wrote bellow. I used an if in the first time the loop runs so the highest and the lowest value are equal your input.

But test also gonewiththewhind answer, and see which is best for you.

Tip: use good variable names

```
int lower,higher;
for(int i=0;i<mesos;i++){ 
    cin >> m;
    if(i==0){ 
        lower = m; 
        higher = m;
    }
    if(m>higher) higher = m;
    else if(m<lower) lower = m;
}
```

Comment: ??? `cin << m`?  did you mean `cin >> m` or `cout << m`?

Comment: You could eliminate the `if` statement, by reading `m` before the loop and assign the value to `lower` and `higher`.  The loop condition would be `i < (mesos - 1)`.

Comment: Thomas matthews, you're right on both comments. But he is using the assignment inside the loop which is why I used it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just for elegance as this is a C++ question.

```
uint64_t min, max;
for(decltype(mesos) i = 0; i < mesos; ++i) {
  std::cin >> m;
  min = std::min(min, m);
  max = std::max(max, m);
}
```

Comment: ??? `cin << m`?  Did you mean `cin >> m` or `cout << m`?

Comment: that definitely won't compile, edited :)